# Calculate age (year, month, day) using DateDiff in stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird, date-arithmetic, firebird2.1

I need to show the time that has passed since a specific date in years, months and days, **taking leap years/months into account**. This has to be within a stored producedure in Firebird 2.1.

I'm struggling with the following code:

```
  SELECT CASE
    WHEN :CustomDateTime > CURRENT_DATE THEN 0
    WHEN EXTRACT(YEARDAY FROM :CustomDateTime) > EXTRACT(YEARDAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, :CustomDateTime, CURRENT_DATE) - 1
    ELSE DATEDIFF(YEAR, :CustomDateTime, CURRENT_DATE)
  END
  FROM RDB$DATABASE
  INTO :YearDiff;

  SELECT CASE
    WHEN :CustomDateTime > CURRENT_DATE THEN 0
    WHEN (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM :CustomDateTime) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE))
       AND (EXTRACT(YEARDAY FROM :CustomDateTime) > EXTRACT(YEARDAY FROM CURRENT_DATE))
      THEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, DATEADD(:YearDiff YEAR TO :CustomDateTime), CURRENT_DATE) - 1
    ELSE DATEDIFF(MONTH, DATEADD(:YearDiff YEAR TO :CustomDateTime), CURRENT_DATE)
  END
  FROM RDB$DATABASE
  INTO :MonthDiff;

  SELECT CASE
    WHEN :CustomDateTime > CURRENT_DATE THEN 0
    WHEN (:YearDiff > 0) AND (:MonthDiff > 0) THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(:MonthDiff MONTH TO DATEADD(:YearDiff YEAR TO :CustomDateTime)), CURRENT_DATE)
    WHEN (:YearDiff > 0) AND (:MonthDiff = 0) THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(:YearDiff YEAR TO :CustomDateTime), CURRENT_DATE)
    WHEN (:YearDiff = 0) AND (:MonthDiff > 0) THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(:MonthDiff MONTH TO :CustomDateTime), CURRENT_DATE)                
    ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, :CustomDateTime, CURRENT_DATE)
  END
  FROM RDB$DATABASE
  INTO :DayDiff;
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: No one can offer suggestions on how to fix the code unless you describe what doesn't work.

Comment: How do you want to handle Feb 29 birthdays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in pl/sql, but you can use this idea for finding the time passed since v_date;

```
 set serveroutput on;
    declare
    v_date date := '27-APR-16';
    PROCEDURE passed(toCheck date) IS 
             years INTEGER := 0;
             months INTEGER := 0;
             days INTEGER := 0;
    BEGIN
            SELECT floor(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, toCheck)) into months FROM dual;
            SELECT SYSDATE - ADD_MONTHS(toCheck, months) INTO days FROM dual;
            years := floor(months / 12);
            months := months - (years * 12);
            dbms_output.put_line('Yers : ' || years || ', ' || ' Months : ' || months || ', Days: ' || days);
    END passed;
    begin
        passed(v_date);
    end;
```